# How to set open graph tags for Facebook like button?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I have the following elements in my page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
...

<meta property="og:title" content="testitle"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.hoteljo.de"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.hoteljo.de/images/button-60.png"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="site name"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="id"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1160534546"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="description"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'id',
             status: true,
             cookie: true,
             xfbml: true});
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>

   <fb:like href='http://www.hoteljo.de' send='false' layout='button_count'    
 show_faces='false' font='verdana'></fb:like>
```

I inserted the open graph description in the head and included the Facebook like button inside the body element. 
But still on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug I get error. What do I have to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the page http://www.hoteljo.de redirect to http://www.hoteljo.de/signup via a 302 HTTP code. So Facebook can't parse OpenGraphs from the home page http://www.hoteljo.de !

You should try to remove that redirection or to set it up with javascript (as this is a temporary redirection).

Comment: I fixed that but as you see on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.hoteljo.de it is still not working. What else can I do?

Comment: Hmmm ... can't see any other problem that may cause this error message o_o ...
More strange : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hoteljo.de Facebook seems to receive no answer from your server at all ...
Sorry not being to help you more here.

Comment: when I click on like I get a different image on my Facebook wall than I specified:  
       <meta property="go:image"    content="http://www.hoteljo.de/images/hoteljo60.png"/> why is this so?

Comment: Facebook doesn't seem to want to reparse your website ... so he took the first image it found on the last parse ... and as the last parse was with the redirection problem, it didn't cared about your OG tags.

As soon as facebook will accept to parse correctly your site, that problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular redirection path error:

see https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.site.de

Your original URL (http://www.site.de/) links to another URL (https://www.office-site.de/) which links back to your original URL (http://www.site.de/) through the rel="canonical" link in your  and so on.

Decide what your canonical URL is, and stick to that.

Comment: http://www.site.de/ is not the site of interest.

my site is http://www.hoteljo.de